# Upload image without form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm looking for the most streamlined way of uploading images to insert them into a text that a user is typing.

So while the user is typing into a textarea I want him to be able to click an icon which will open the file browsing dialog of the browser. After choosing an image I want it to be uploaded automatically and have the url inserted in the text field.

Unfortunately I don't really have an idea how to solve this.

One idea is to use a hidden file input field and 'click' it using js. But how can i submit the hidden form after an image got chosen without the need of an additional submit button?

**EDIT:** Of course I want to archive this using ajax. The server side should be easy as it just receives the data and returns the URL. What I need to know is how to trigger the file browser dialog and then trigger the ajax request when the user presses "open".

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need some PHP and AJAX. At least something server-side.

Comment: Not necessarily PHP. Some server-side code, though

Comment: you can use submit function of the form https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. This is only about the client side. Server side should be easy as it just receives the data. @DawidC : That looks good, but how do I trigger the submit when the user clicks on the "open" button in the file browser dialog?

Comment: @JasonTS you should listen for change event on input (of the type file) ex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the images inline where the user is typing that's going to be a little more difficult as you'd need to emulate a textbox that's really just a div that you're allowing the user to edit. I say this because you can't render images into a text input or textarea attribute.

If that is what you want you're probably going to need HTML5 loving browsers because `contenteditable` is going to be the attribute you'll want to play with there.

Depending on your time constraints, and for simplicity sake; I would suggest having something like this system has where there is a preview. You could have a styled form to look like a button that they click. `<input type="file"/>` will give you all the browse functionality you need, from there you can attach a submit action to the onchange event of the input to fire the information to the backend.